# How to get base class's generic type parameter?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have three class as following:

```
public class TestEntity { }

public class BaseClass<TEntity> { }

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass<TestEntity> { }
```

I already get the `System.Type` object of `DerivedClass` using reflection in runtime. How can I get the `System.Type` object of `TestEntity` using reflection?

Thanks.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I assume that your code is just a sample and you don't explicitly know `DerivedClass`.

```
var type = GetSomeType();
var innerType = type.BaseType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
```

Note that this code can fail very easily at run time you should verify if type you handle is what you expect it to be:

```
if(type.BaseType.IsGenericType 
     && type.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(BaseClass<>))
```

Also there can be deeper inheritance tree so some loop with above condition would be required.

Comment: I get DerivedClass's type object dynamically, so can not hard-coding. I have Resolved.

Comment: I did not hard-code `DerivedClass` there is stub `var type = GetSomeType();`

Answer (score 6):

You can use the BaseType property. The following code would be resilient for changes in the inheritance (e.g. if you add another class in the middle):

```
Type GetBaseType(Type type)
{
   while (type.BaseType != null)
   {
      type = type.BaseType;
      if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(BaseClass<>))
      {
          return type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
      }
   }
   throw new InvalidOperationException("Base type was not found");
}

// to use:
GetBaseType(typeof(DerivedClass))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var derivedType = typeof(DerivedClass);
var baseClass = derivedType.BaseType;
var genericType = baseClass.GetGenericArguments()[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

It think this should work:

```
var firstGenericArgumentType = typeof(DerivedClass).BaseType.GetGenericArguments().FirstOrDefault();
```

Or

```
var someObject = new DerivedClass();
var firstGenericArgumentType = someObject.GetType().BaseType.GetGenericArguments().FirstOrDefault();
```