# How to get generic property but ignore its type?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection

I have a struct that is essentially a Key Value Pair. I have another class that has multiple properties of these MyStruct (the key is a string and the value is T) or some other type. I want to get all of the properties and call their ToString function on the value, e.g.

```
foreach (var prop in AllTheProperties)
{
  if (prop.GetType() is typeof(MyStruct<ignoreMe>)
  {
   yield return prop.Key;
   yield return prop.Value.ToString();
   }
}
```

But where I get stuck is on the typing part. I don't want to get all of the type strings, then type int, etc. How can I ignore the type? (on a side note, this will be ported to VB, but I prefer to do some things in c# first).

Comment: You may want to add (1) the `MyStruct` code and (2) code that at least resembles what your "other class" that contains properties of `MyStruct`looks like  to your question.

Comment: I have removed your Vb.Net tag as the question is in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assign your `MyStruct<T>` object an interface that has a property of `string Key` and a read-only property of `object ObjectValue`.  Then I would just return the `Value` in the implementation for the `ObjectValue` property.  Here is an example:

```
public interface GenericMyStruct
{
    string Key { get; set; }

    object ObjectValue { get; }
}

public class MyStruct<T> : GenericMyStruct
{
    public string Key { get; set; }

    public T Value { get; set; }

    public object ObjectValue { get { return (object)Value; } }
}
```

Your code which writes out all of your properties would then look something like this:

```
foreach (var prop in AllTheProperties)
{
    if (prop is GenericMyStruct)
    {
        yield return prop.Key;
        yield return prop.ObjectValue.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I went with this solution; if in doubt, use interfaces, I guess :)

Answer (score 3):

If all what you are after is to make sure that the generic type used is MyStruct regardless of the T, the you have to compare the generic type definition only.

```
Type propType = prop.GetType();
if(propType.IsGenericType && propType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(MyStruct<>))
{
    //Do work
}
```

This will always return true if the object of type MyStruct regardless of the generic type arguments.

Credit:- [How to get base class's generic type parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087606/how-to-get-base-classs-generic-type-parameter)

Answer (score 1):

Using this method. It uses reflection and LINQ to just call ToString of all public properties of an array of any objects.

```
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetAllPropsAsStrings(object[] objs)
    {
        return from obj in objs from prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties() select prop.GetValue(obj).ToString();
    }
```

Example usage using two different keyvaluepairs, but this will work with your own custom struct as well:

```
        KeyValuePair<string, int> blah = new KeyValuePair<string, int>("hello", 42);
        KeyValuePair<int, int> blah2 = new KeyValuePair<int, int>(22, 42);

        var stringarray = GetAllPropsAsStrings(new object[] {blah, blah2});
        foreach (string str in stringarray)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(str);
        }
```