# how to get base class generic type parameter in typescript using reflection api

Tags: generics, reflection, typescript

I need to extract Props interface from my React component to get documentation
see this typescript wiki issue
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-wiki/issues/65

.net analog [How to get base class's generic type parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087606/how-to-get-base-classs-generic-type-parameter)

Answer (score -3):

Typescript is just Javascript. There is no reflection. It's not C#, it's not a real object oriented language.

So if you want to extract the properties of your js object you have to use javascript.

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/86014/1134380) to see how to.

Comment: Why is it "not a real object oriented language"?

Comment: In Javascript you can't create class, you can't use inheritance or any feature of the OOP. When you create a class in Typescript, the transpiled code is just a set of JS tricks to simulate an OO class.

Comment: From Wikipedia: "Object-oriented programming (OOP) is a programming language model organized around objects rather than "actions" and data rather than logic." - It is true that JavaScript does not have classes, but you can instantiate types, since objects can have constructors. Data and functions can be scoped to an object, and exist per-object instance. You can DEFINITELY use inheritance in JavaScript (otherwise it wouldn't be possible in TypeScript either). I would argue that whilst JavaScript is not a "classical" OOP language (with classes/interfaces etc), it is a prototypical OOP language.

Comment: Javascript has some OOP features but not all (like polymorphism). This is why for me it is "not a real object oriented language". I don't want to go further on this classic debate and it's off-topic.

Comment: Oh dear, this is rapidly turning into a battle of wits with the unarmed. Since JavaScript can use inheritance, by definition it can also use polymorphism.

Comment: You dont understand me, i think.
I want to get interface data. Not object data.
Not in run-time. What does OOP, Inheritance to do with it.
I just want to get info from parser/analyzer
For example, https://github.com/reactjs/react-docgen extract info about props fron javascript NOT IN RUN-TIME